# How do I calculate the DC blocking capacitor at the output of a transistor amplifier?

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, impedance

Suppose this circuit of an audio amplifier:

[image]

How is `C` calculated?

I suppose `C` is there to block DC, so it is a high pass filter.

If this is the case the formula for `C` would be something like

```
C = 1/2ΠRf
```

I can choose for example, `f = 20Hz` but what about `R`
?

How do I know the output impedance of that circuit?

Comment: You need to know (or specify) the input impedance of the next stage. The output impedance is just R_L || r_e.

Comment: this is the last stage.

Comment: Then the next stage is the speakers. Unless you weren't planning to output the audio...

Comment: ahhhhhh, brilliant. This is a headphone amplifier... so it is 32 ohms in my case. Please convert this comment to an answer, so I can accept. thanks.

Comment: Usually, we are using this formula F =1 /(2 *pi * R*C) = 0.16/RC. When R is Rc + RL. So the C = 0.16/(F*R) and F is the lowest frequency you want to amplify, typical around 20Hz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The capacitor forms a high pass filter with whatever impedance is in series with it.  That series impedance is the impedance of the output stage plus the input impedance of whatever is being driven.

Since the cap causes a high pass filter, the filter rolloff frequency needs to be at or a bit below the lowest frequency of interest.  The full "HiFi" audio range is considered to be 20 Hz to 20 kHz.  If you care about the full range, then use a value a bit below 20 Hz, like 10-15 Hz.

Once you have the frequency and the impedance the cap is working against, use the formula you quote to find the minimum capacitance.